# What properties are available to own in Grand Theft Auto V?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

What properties are available to own in Grand Theft Auto V (not GTA Online) and how long before they become profitable?

Comment: Ugh. Why didn't the dupe appear yesterday when I was looking for an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can buy the following properties in Grand Theft Auto V (note some properties can only be bought by certain characters).

## Any

**The Hen House** ($80,000)
$920 (87 weeks before profit)

**Sonar Collections Dock** ($250,000)
$23,000 per collection (11 collections before profit - 30 total)
$250,000 for collecting all 30 (total profit: 940,000)
Bonus: Unlocks "Death at Sea" mission

**Car Scrapyard** ($275,000)
$150 per car (1,834 tows before profit)

**Pitchers** ($750,000)
$7,100 (106 weeks before profit)

**Tequi-la-la** ($2,000,000)
$16,500 (122 weeks before profit)

**Los Santos Golf Club** ($150,000,000)
$264,500 (568 weeks before profit)
Free golf for all players.

## Trevor

**McKenzie Field Hangar** ($150,000)
$7,000 per air mission / $5,000 per ground mission
Bonus: Trevor gets the Cuban 800 and BF Injection vehicles.

**Vanilla Unicorn** (free with "Hang Ten" mission)
$5,000
Bonus: Trevor gets free lap dances and drinks. All characters can use hands.

## Franklin

**LSPD Auto Impound** ($150,000)
$500 per car (300 cars before profit)

**Downtown Cab Co.** ($200,000)
$2,000 (100 weeks before profit)
Bonus: Free taxi rides for Franklin

**Smoke on the Water** ($204,000)
$9,300 (22 weeks before profit)

**Los Santos Customs** ($349,000)
$1,600  (219 weeks before profit)
Bonus: Free custom upgrades for Franklin at the Route 68 location

## Michael

**Cinema Doppler** ($10,000,000)
$132,200 (76 weeks before profit)

**Ten Cent Theater** ($20,000,000)
$264,000 (76 weeks before profit)

**Tivoli Cinema** ($30,000,000)
$142,300 (211 weeks before profit)

## Franklin or Michael

**Hookies** ($600,000)
$4,700  (128 weeks before profit)

## Total Earnings

Once all the properties becomes profitable (max 568 weeks after purchasing them all), the total weekly profit is:

ANY - $289,020 (568 weeks)
TREVOR ONLY - $9700 (128 weeks)
FRANKLIN ONLY - $17,600 (219 weeks)
MICHAEL ONLY - $538,500 (211 weeks)

**NOTE: One week in GTAV equals five hours and 36 minutes in real life.**